# Is there such a thing as completely objective truth?

Tags: epistemology, truth, reality, objectivity

Apologies if this question has been asked before, I looked at similar ones and couldn't find one that answered this exact question.

Is there such a thing as truth completely independent of conditions, axioms or anything of a similar nature? In mathematics (and epistemology as a whole) we generally need to establish a set of axioms before moving forwards, because our perspective and understanding is limited. However, when it comes to reality, I've always believed that the nature of one thing or another is implicit, regardless of our capacity to understand it. We may not understand it or be able to explain it well given the limitations of language and thought but truth simply **is**. If I am missing something please let me know.

Simply put, is there anything about the nature of our universe, existence, etcetera which is only true in respect to certain rules that are accepted? I feel like I'm making a simple thing more complicated than it needs to be. Thank you.

Comment: Added tags 'reality' and 'objectivity'.

Comment: [Pragmatic theories of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_theory_of_truth) are broadly constructivist in their approach to truth. From the article: "Instead of truth being ready-made for us, James asserts we and reality jointly "make" truth. This idea has two senses: (1) truth is mutable, (often attributed to William James and F.C.S. Schiller); and (2) truth is relative to a conceptual scheme (more widely accepted in Pragmatism)." Those of us who accept [constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_science)) see objectivity as a malleable consensus.

Comment: No, such truth would need of a transcendental rule which could validate it, the equivalent of a divine statement; we can't access such domain (see: _noumenon_). So, what is common truth sustained upon? Reason is based on tautologies (see: Kant). I want to survive because I want to exist and vice-versa. 1=1 because it fits my experience, which is possible because 1=1. Any deep fact can be explained by other reasons, in a circular form.

Comment: There is a difference between truth and reality. Truth can only be assigned to statements, and those, obviously, depend on the concepts in them, otherwise they are meaningless. The concepts, in their turn, depend on the type of intellect that conceives them, its resources, etc. So truth *is not* "simply", only reality simply is. And reality is not pre-packaged into any kind of concepts to make sense of "completely independent" truth.

Comment: Your "complete objective truth" spec sounds like Kant's [Thing-in-itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing-in-itself), and by Kant's Critique, our minds may attempt to correlate in useful ways, perhaps even closely accurate ways, with the structure and order of the various aspects of the universe, but cannot know these "things-in-themselves" (noumena) directly. As a concession if you'd like to formulate your desired truth in such correlated inference, then it must be language dependent and it's nontrivial to find such a formula in any expressively adequate languages or metalang per logic...

Comment: No you are using the term wrongly. Epistemology does not need axioms. Axioms are a math thing not philosophy. Propositions are what philosophy about. Propositions are objectively true or false by definition. True meaning universally true. That is true everywhere across a domain. For instance "all women are human beings" is certainly true everywhere on Earth. There are no false instances or counter examples. Propositions are not sentences nor statements. They are ideas expressed in a language for others to understand & that value true or false applies to reality. Do not buy the semantics attemp

Comment: Do not buy the semantics attempts like definitions can change. Sentences are not propositions.  I can Express the exact same intentional.meaning in 10 different languages. I can say "My cat Tibby  is colored black" in 10 different languages & all refer to the same exact same cat. I would not have 10 different  propositions. There would be 10 different ways to write it. The intent on what you are expressing remains King. I don't care how you say it but what you say is important: a true proposition or false. Objective refers to the highest level of truth humans have. Truths that are constant.

Comment: There are distinct types of truth. Contingent truths are temporary such as it is raining or statements about your age. These are not necessarily constants in truth value. The answer can change from one day to another day. Objective truth does not change in value. All even numbers are divisible by 2 is an objective truth no matter how you express it as long as we are clear on the domain. The most frequently used objection is HOW CAN YOU KNOW? How is it that you can't distinguish your awareness & a truth value? A truth value is independent of your awareness to the truth value.

Comment: Your awareness of the proposition "there is life on Jupiter" is not the discussion! If the proposition above is meaningful then the proposition only can have exactly one truth value forever. That value can never change or the proposition is not objective as stated. It would prove contingent if the value fluctuates from true to false.  Objective truth propositions can never change by someone who is in authority or power alone.  There is no boss or superiors in objective truths. This is why ancient philosophers disagreed so much;  no one was under another philosopher. Philosophy is not opinions

Comment: If you insist on using Mathematical logic or math language then objective truths are either propositions that are called tautological in mathematics or the proposition will be called a contradiction as defined in mathematics specifically. There is no third option. The proposition would not be objectively true if it fits a different category.  One should note some terminology between Mathematics & Philosophy are NOT IDENTICAL. That is the exact same word is used with the same spelling & pronunciation but the contexts in meaning are NOT IDENTICAL. You being a human is objectively true yes or no?

Comment: @Logikal Well, if we define human and we define "me" (because that's an entire question of philosophy itself) then I believe we can eventually reach a consensus that the statement is objectively true. As far as I can see, it would be a statement that needs not rely on any axioms – it just sits on a couple of definitions, and words are just our way of describing concepts that exist with or without us. So, as far as I can see, it's possible to have an objective truth.

Answer (score 2):

Truth is the correspondence to reality, self evident, universal, global, timeless and absolute.

Let's just assume the following (false) statement for a moment:

> There is no objective truth

The verb *is* implies an assertion about the objective order of things, the conformity to reality. This would be a contradiction in itself, since the existence of objective truth cannot be evaluated without objectiveness.

Objective truth must therefore not only exist, but is a prerequisite for objective assertions to be made at all.

Physics reveals objective truth. Mathematics reveals objective truth. Without objective truth, science couldn't exist at all.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like what you're essentially saying is the pursuit of truth or even attempt to express truth implies the existence of it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's the correspondent theory of truth. :D There are others. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Major_theories). Objectivity might be seen as consensual [intersubjectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersubjectivity).

Comment: Can you expand on "The verb is implies an assertion about the objective order of things, the conformity to reality." It would be of interest to me to consider a formal argument.

Comment: Newtonian Mechanics is not truth, just a good approximation. General Relativity is a better approximation, but not really truth, it doesn't include gravitation...

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you will find a satisfactory answer for this question.

The topic of "Truth" is very complicated, and there are many different approaches on how to handle it. There is no objective, common, understanding of what "Truth" is, at all. It is very hard to answer questions like this on concepts that are for all intents or purposes more or less undefined, or defined in several different ways by different people.

To get some insight into what people have thought on that, just take an eagle's eyes view on the table-of-contents of the corresponding [Wikipedia page on Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth). One book that stands out is "Kirkham, R: Theories of Truth: A Critical Introduction (Bradford Books)", which talks about Truth within more than 400 pages.

The same goes for concepts like "reality", "existence", "universe", "matter", "time" and so on... all of those are squishy and up to discussion/definition.

For a real chance at answering your question, you'd have to specify the context in which you are asking - or in other words, provide axioms. Which leads us back in a circle to your question of whether it is to provide Truth directly, without having anything else to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Completely objective or absolute truth is like infinity, a name for a notion, rather than an actual physical reality. An assumption at best, but workable as such. In practice you can assume your own existence to be absolute truth, simply because as subjective as it may seem, that is as absolute as it will ever get to you.

In science, objective truth is generated by simply ignoring all objectives except the ones covered by the assumption. This allows for abstraction of problems and solutions that may or may not work in real life.

In my opinion, one of the most underestimated and undervalued experiences in life  is finding out how wrong you are. The stuff I am writing right now, could be the most ignorant nonsense ever written, but there is only one way to find out if it is. Absolute truth serves as an instrument to get there.

So,... is there such a thing as completely objective truth?

It may seem scary sometimes, but there is if you say there is, because you say there is. On a cosmic scale, there is no up or down until someone calls it.

Comment: So that's the thing, since this is my perspective and there's no way to really prove it to be true or untrue, I'm trying to see if there's anyone who can say otherwise. If not, I will have to accept it as "as close to the truth as possible," in the style of the scientific method.

Comment: @EthanDandelion  My point exactly. That plus the fact that one should take pride in getting minus votes on this site. The better answers are seldom the ones at the top. You know, the ones with all the votes must be those supported by objective truth. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is an important part of [epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology), which is concerned with knowledge in general. Here you will find different philosophers defining the meaning of 'truth' in various ways. Those that believe that there is such a thing as (objective) 'truth' will often argue that truth is about a correspondence between between a thought/knowledge and a world that's independent of the mind, which is known as the [correspondence theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theory_of_truth). In light of this the question then becomes about what and how we can know the outside world.

More specifically the doubt whether one can know anything would fall under [Philosophical skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_skepticism) which has taken various shapes throughout history.

This should hopefully give you the terms to be able to research these questions.

---

Personally the way I 'answered' this question for myself is that all relative knowledge - no matter what the large majority of knowledge - is one way or another based on other knowledge. At the 'start' of this web (wherever it may be) of relative knowledge there is either objective knowledge or relative knowledge. IF it is relative, then all my knowledge is meaningless including my reasoning about the meaningfulness of knowledge. Thus the *only* meaningful possibility is that the 'start' of this tree *requires* objective knowledge.

Where such objective knowledge could enter our web of knowledge becomes a more complex question, and before one can even consider that one would have to consider which knowledge claims *could* even be objective (regardless of whether they are). Many philosophers have argued that human perception would (have to) be objective in this way, but I never was able to justify their reasoning (also worth reading about [realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_realism) and [idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealism) in general). More broadly religions have a decent conceptual basis for the **claim** that the things they describe are events where objective knowledge entered our web. And then there is stuff like Plato's ideals and all that, but that all gets far too 'vague' for me.

And all that still leaves me with the belief that all knowledge I have is relative, and that the best thing I can do is to get 'closer' to objective knowledge. The question becomes more 'how to judge the quality of a truth claim' and not 'is this true?'.

Answer (score 1):

I think objective absolutely exists. Whether we understand things or not, they will go on existing, they will be governed by laws of the universe.
One might say, well how do you know the laws of universe won't change over time?Well, if they do, then there will be a reason and truth for it that maybe we don't understand, but like Molder from X-Files says, "The truth is out there"

And ya, 1+2=2, the distance from me and my refrigerator is less distance then from me and the moon. There is more mass in 100lb then 50lb...there are so many absolute truths it actually astonishes me that people want to argue this for the sake of arguing...
quoting them saying " ya but what about physics, do we know everything about physics? "
No we don't need to understand everything to know that truth exists.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Our concept of truth is based on our assumptions about our reality -- we assume that this reality actually exits (and is not a figment of our imagination) and that it has certain properties. Those assumptions, I believe, are the axioms that you have mentioned. They cannot be proven once and for all, but their validity can be tested. Or, rather, we can make certain predictions based on those axioms, and those predictions can be tested (and that's what science is about).

And, I agree again, usually we make those assumptions intuitively and, therefore, implicitly. Here, however, is my attempt to spell them out:

1. We all share and belong to one and only objective reality. "Objective" means that the existence of the reality itself and of everything that happens in it is independent of our awareness of those things, and of our own existence.
2. In this reality, nothing happens at random but every thing can be traced to its cause in the past. In other words, this reality is deterministic.
3. We, humans, can identify the patterns, in the ways the causes create their effects, and imagine the processes driving those patterns. By doing so, we achieve an *understanding* of how this world works, and use this understanding to accomplish the things we want, shaping this reality to our liking. It is this understanding that we call truth (or *knowledge* of the truth).<sup>1</sup>

Aside from our capacity to understand (and to know the truth), we also have a separate mental faculty that let us make statistical (or intuitive) inferences about our circumstances. This comes handy whenever our understanding is lacking (which is often because we are not born "preinstalled" with any of it).

<sup>1</sup> This understanding (and its truth) is individual -- it gets created by and belongs to the person who put it together. However, since we all aim to understand the same objective reality, our understandings of it, and our truths, should also be the same -- and often they are.

Answer (score 0):

Objectivity arises , changes and vanishes.
For example - consider the objective truth , food or fuel is always required for life or a machine to function properly. The truth is objective as it is true for all biological or non-biological systems. There is no dispute. However the nature of fuel or food can change.It can change  from gasoline to diesel to petrol to electricity for mechanical systems. It can change from grass to vegetables and plants to flesh etc for life systems. The requirements for food or fuel can even vanish if we believe the religions.

Another objective truth is : matter attracts matter. Whether we are talking about earthly matters or liquid matter or gaseous matter or photons or atoms or dark matter , matter always attracts matter.
There are theories which tend to modify the objectivity but the fact remains that matter attracts matter. We have yet to see how this truth vanishes in certain cases.

Another objective truth is : Functional knowledge always increases with time as time moves forward.  This is true regardless of who is speaking. However even this truth arises , changes(as there is a change in field of interest) and vanishes. It vanishes if we go backward in time in future. It is speculative for most of us but there is nothing in physics which stops it from happening.

Answer (score 0):

One way around your conundrum is to consider true to be a label invented by humans that is applied conventionally in certain circumstances. For example, in mathematics the label true is applied to statements that follow from the axioms. The label true is also conventionally applied to statements about reality which appear to us as being in accord with reality. In England, it tends to be warmer in summer than in winter, is a statement that  would be considered true in that sense. Whether you would consider that statement to be completely objective depends on how you use those words. I suspect most people would accept the statement as being completely objective, while others might point out that England, winter and summer are products of the human mind. Others might say that idea of an average temperature is a human concept- that in 'reality' the temperature is what it is at an instant. Others might say that temperature itself is a human construct, a label we have invented to refer to the amount of kinetic energy possessed by atoms and molecules in a region of space. Others might say that the idea of atoms and molecules is a human one, etc etc. Necessarily, any understanding we have of reality is through the lens of the human mind, and in that sense there is inevitably some degree of subjectivity. Whether you consider that degree of subjectivity to be important or merely a quibble is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Heidegger's phenomenology is knocked sideways by Derrida's deconstruction, putting paid to a certain truth.  In Heidegger's phenomenology beings come from Being and truth is the truth of Being.  The beings (living or inanimate) have their characteristics, but as their foundation Being is altogether different—i.e. not *a* being—otherwise the foundation would contain what it founds.  Being is the nouminal clearing—the surroundings from which beings discern their objects, correctly or mistakenly.  E.g. [Letter on Humanism](https://www.beyng.com/pages/en/BasicWritings/BasicWritings.235.html)

> metaphysics recognizes the clearing of Being either solely as the view
> of what is present in "outward appearance" (*idea*) or critically as
> what is seen as a result of categorial representation on the part of
> subjectivity. This means that the truth of Being as the clearing
> itself remains concealed for metaphysics. However, this concealment is
> not a defect of metaphysics but a treasure withheld from it yet held
> before it, the treasure of its own proper wealth.

So the truth of the nouminal 'out-there' is concealed.  This is fairly standard.  On to Derrida's deconstruction: [Reciprocal destroyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure,_Sign,_and_Play_in_the_Discourse_of_the_Human_Sciences#Reciprocal_destroyers)

> Derrida depicts Nietzsche, Freud, and Heidegger, three of his greatest
> influences, as ultimately trapped within a destructive spiral of
> denunciation. ...
>
> > They are all more or less naïve, more or less empirical, more or less
> > systematic, more or less close to the formulation or even to the
> > formalization of [their] circle. It is these differences which explain
> > the multiplicity of destructive discourses and the disagreement
> > between those who make them. It was within concepts inherited from
> > metaphysics that Nietzsche, Freud, and Heidegger worked, for example.
> > Since these concepts are not elements or atoms and since they are
> > taken from a syntax and a system, every particular borrowing drags
> > along with it the whole of metaphysics. This is what allows these
> > destroyers to destroy each other reciprocally—for example, Heidegger,
> > considering Nietzsche, with as much lucidity and rigor as bad faith
> > and misconstruction, as the last metaphysician, the last "Platonist."
> > One could do the same for Heidegger himself, for Freud, or for a
> > number of others.

No one's system has the monopoly.  Even the truth of the noumenon is shakable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there absolutely is *emphasized text* an objective truth, which is observable and verifiable. Truth like that is scary, people don't want to hear objective truth. Objective truth is the way things are, people wanna deny it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Is there such a thing as truth completely independent of conditions, axioms or anything of a similar nature?**

No, I don’t think so. In mathematics, the concepts, symbols, and so forth must together make sense. So it is true in physics, chemistry, and other hard sciences.

But the key concept is "to make sense." To do so, the data and the reasoning process must follow the laws of logic. Such laws supply the conditions and axioms that truth is dependent upon.

Good question.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there such a thing as completely objective truth?

Yes, there definitely is!
At least:

"You asked that question on this site". (At some "period in time"...)

("As long (English) "language" "has meaning"...)

Comment: So a "more absolute"/time robust truth: There was/is/will be "doubt"! ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does OP know he's not a brain-in-a-jar, being fed false memories of this moment and images of this post? Something to consider.

Comment: Then...they also must have jared & fed you&me ...(and all witnesses) (so we can never know about the jars and the feeding, but when we (1-all) have been fed with the same "truth", it is getting "completely objective"...and these "brains in jars guys" (there is no "reality"..) they can also "touch children", @ConnieMnemonic !?

Comment: The problem you have @xerx598 is that, from OPs perspective, you can't prove that you exist. You know that you're real, but OP doesn't. You and I could just be an illusion in the jar to make the whole thing more convincing.

Comment: Descartes and me can (prove that "we exist"), but I get your point...: All "truth" is "subjective" ... But still: is there "a noise" when there is no listener/subject!?

Answer (score -3):

Ultimately, no.  Truth depends on power, like the postmodernist said; however, that power is called GOD and, practically, we don't get to decide what the Truth is at our own convenience.